# How do I flatten JSON data of the Pandascore E-Sports GET response format to have a very clean dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, json, bash, pandas, curl

I am trying to get a nice pandas dataframe of a JSON file I got from the PandaScore REST API. I realize that in order to do this, I need to flatten the values which contain lists and dictionaries, but I am getting errors.

For this reason, I was not sure exactly how to proceed. As far as the dataframe which I get from directly reading the JSON file in pandas, I get this.
[image: Data Frame Part 1]
[image: Data Frame Part 2]
As you can see from the output, columns contain lists of JSON objects and so I want to flatten these lists and objects so the final dataframe looks much more clean and interpretable.

If it helps to have the original JSON file to do this, you can get it from here. 
[CS GO Teams JSON File](http://ge.tt/6945rXv2)
I first used curl to make an API call to PandaScore to get an array of JSON objects for the first page of Counter-Strike Global Offensive teams. The JSON response looks like this.

[image: REST API Response]

I am still quite new to working with curl so I was not sure how to save this response to a file immediately so I just copied the response and put it into a JSON file. After doing this; however, the format was not how I envisioned it so I ended up piping the response content in the file to a nicely, formatted JSON using jq in the terminal.

After doing that, I got a JSON file which now looks like this:

[image: JSON Part 1] 
[image: JSON Part 2]
[image: JSON Part 3]
I realize for flattening the JSON file in pandas, you can use the normalize json function from pandas, but I wasn't sure how to get it work. To get the dictionary form, I tried using the JSON module in Python to get the dictionary and then pass in that dictionary to the function, but it did not work. I also tried reading the original dataframe from pandas using the following.

```py
import json 
# Experiment 1
data = str(open("data/cs-go-teams.json")) 
dataDict = json.loads(data)  
import pandas as pd 
from pandas.io.json import normalize_json
# Experiment 2 
data = pd.read_json("cs-go-teams.json") 
dataDict = data.to_dict()
normalizedData = normalize_json(dataDict)
```

Error 1:
[image: Error 1]
Error 2:
[image: Error 2]

My hunch is that there is something wrong in the JSON formatting of the file which is causing this problem.

If it's something else though, I would be happy to learn from your expertise and experiences to grow as a developer working with JSON data.

Other than these two experiments, I was also looking into how to do the further flattening for more complexly structured JSON objects. An article on Medium written by Amir Ziai provides a custom function that flattens the lists and dictionaries nested in the object recursively. If this may be of any help, I am providing the article as a link to your convenience.

[Medium Article](https://towardsdatascience.com/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10)

That's all I did so far. Stackoverflow community, I am actively looking for your help to figure out my shortcomings in understanding this entire process from the data collection to the JSON format to how the flattening works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json 
import pandas as pd 
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with open('cs-go-teams.json', 'rb') as file:
    df = json.load(file)

players_data = json_normalize(df, record_path = 'players', meta = ['acronym', 'id','image_url','name','slug'],  meta_prefix = 'team_')
```

Open the file, load it into a df, then investigate the players data, then append the team data to each player. You will just have to change the file path in the open() statement.

Comment: Ben, this is so beautiful! Thank you so much for this awesome and simple code!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for providing the JSON example. The code below worked to convert it into a pandas `DataFrame`. This is without using `import json` function.

```
# Import Libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Set null equal to None
null = None
```

**Assign the json to a variable**

Please note that it is a list that has multiple dictionaries within.

```
data = data = [
  {
    "slug": "infinity-esports-cs-go",
    "players": [
      {
        "slug": "cruzn",
        "role": null,
        "name": "CruzN",
        "last_na
...
]
```

**Code below parses the json and nested json to put in a dataframe**

The columns may be renamed as needed

```
# Create empty lists
list_slug, list_players, list_name, list_image_url, list_id, list_current_videogame, list_acronym = [], [], [], [], [], [], []
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range (len(data)):
    list_slug.append(data[i]['slug'])
    list_players.append(data[i]['players'])
    list_name.append(data[i]['name'])
    list_image_url.append(data[i]['image_url'])
    list_current_videogame.append(data[i]['current_videogame'])
    list_acronym.append(data[i]['acronym'])
    list_id.append(data[i]['id'])
    #temp['players'] = data[i]['players']
    #print(data[i]['slug'])


    # Create dataframe for 'current_videogame'
    tvid = pd.DataFrame({'current_videogame_slug':[data[i]['current_videogame']['slug']],
                     'current_videogame_name':[data[i]['current_videogame']['name']],
                     'current_videogame_id':[data[i]['current_videogame']['id']]
                    })
    tvid['flag']=data[i]['slug']

    # Create dataframe for 'players'
    tplayer = pd.DataFrame(data[i]['players'])
    tplayer.columns = ['players_' + str(col) for col in tplayer.columns]
    tplayer['flag'] = data[i]['slug']

    # Merge 'current_videogame' and 'players'
    tjoin = pd.merge(tplayer, tvid, on='flag', how='outer')

    # Merge with main dataframe
    temp = pd.DataFrame({'slug':list_slug, 'name':list_name, 'image_url':list_image_url,'acronym': list_acronym, 'id':id})
    temp2 = pd.merge(temp, tjoin, left_on='slug', right_on='flag', how='outer')

    df = df.append(temp2)
    df = df.drop(columns=['flag'])
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Nilesh. This looked like quite a bit of work, but I am very thankful to you for taking the time to make this solution. I definitely learned a lot from your solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

this may be among the errors that are surpessed by the `errors='ignore'` paramater to the `json_normalize` function -- check the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html). this is only available for `pandas` version  >= 0.20, though, so check your version (`pd.__version__`)